# How to sum json value after sorted in java android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, sorting

Following Json needs to group by city to get array along with count if city have same array value. after that I want to sort the 2 biggest and the rest are added together, but how to do it?

```
{
"data": [
        {
            "ID": 47,
            "city": "Jakarta"
        },
        {
            "ID": 48,
            "city": "Bogor"
        },
        {
           "ID": 49,
            "city": "Bogor"
        },
        {
            "ID": 50,
            "city": "Jakarta"
        },
        {
            "ID": 51,
            "city": "Jakarta"
        },
        {
            "ID": 52,
            "city": "Bali"
        },
        {
            "ID": 50,
            "city": "Lampung"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i have tried so far is group by city to get array

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").length();i++){
            JSONObject innerJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i);
            String key = innerJsonObject.getString("city");
            if(hashMap.containsKey(key)){
                int count = hashMap.get(key)+1;
                hashMap.put(key,count);
            }else {
                hashMap.put(key,1);
            }
        }
        Log.e("Hashmap---",hashMap.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the result is :

- Bogor = 2
- Jakarta = 3
- Bali = 1
- Lampung = 1

**the expected result is :**

- Jakarta = 3
- Bogor = 2
- Another city = 2

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581754/5031209

Answer (score 0):

Try to add that HashMap into TreeMap  after the for loop like this

```
     Map<String, Integer> reverseSortedMap = new TreeMap<String, 
        Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());

      reverseSortedMap.putAll(hashMap);//your hashMap with count of city

      System.out.println("Reverse Sorted Map   : " + reverseSortedMap);
```